# Manage a session steps with angular

Tags: angularjs, routes

My angular ui uses a REST API with my node server to manage something I call "sessions" which are a sequence of successive steps (3 or 4 for now).

When the server sends a "next round" order to the web ui (via a socket.io mechanism), I need to replace my step 1 view (view-step1.html) with the step 2 view (view-step2.html).

I saw the usual way to replace views in Angular is ui routing but it seems odd to me to get something like `ip/#/session/step1` or `ip/#/session/step2` because steps are server-managed and I don't really want the user to be allowed to get back to a previous step that would be desynchronized with the real server-step. (for instance, server is at the step 3, and I enter ip/#session/step1 in my URL bar).

What would be the common way to change views according to a server orders?

Comment: What about something like `<div ng-include="'view-step' + stepNo + '.html'"></div>` inside you main template?

Comment: It works perfectly but I'm wondering if I really respect the angular philosophy in my case. That why I explained the context above.

Comment: Well, I'd go with the regular routing as you mentioned above. For preventing manual url changes or desyncs with the server side, you can implement Listeners for `$routeChangeStart` (or `$stateChangeStart` if you use ui-router) and see if the route / state step matches your server sided step - otherwise route to the correct step.

Comment: "desynchronized with the real server-step" your rest api need to handle this case and refused the request if the user is not allow.

Comment: It's also a matter of previous/next browser buttons management. If the user clicks on "back" and Ui is on step 2, I don't really want the URL to be "/#/session/step1" and to raise an error.
But as I'm a newbie in angular and routing management, it's maybe the usual way to manage this case.